# "Your GitHub user account does not have access to this repo" on the admin url of the gatsby blog deployed on netlify

Tags: github, deployment, oauth, gatsby, netlify

I'm trying to setup gatsby blog and followed all the instructions from their [documentation](https://w3layouts.com/delog-gatsby-starter-netlify-cms/). Everything worked fine, but when I go to the admin URL of the site and try to log in, then it says **"Your GitHub user account does not have access to this repo"**. I have authorized to give access to the repositories but still, I can't log in. And thus, I can't access the CMS. Why does it happening?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not authorized properly the application.
You need to [configure the settings repository](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/repo-permissions-linking/).

In your repository settings (https://github.com/settings/installations) you should have the Netlify application ready to be configured and the proper OAuth. There, you will need to select your project:

[image]

Then, under https://app.netlify.com/sites/YOUR_SITE_URL/settings/identity, configure the previous auth access:

[image]

Comment: I did as you said but getting the same message.

Comment: Can you paste your `config.yml`, your backend settings? In addition, what do you have in the "Authorized GitHub apps" (in your repo settings)?

Comment: I did again from scratch and my repo name on GitHub is `gatsby-starter-delog` and at the time of deployment, Netlify asks for the repo name and I entered `gatsby-starter-delog-blog` becuase the repo names can not be the same. Now, I'm confused in what should be the repo name in `config.yml`? By default it is `repo: W3Layouts/gatsby-starter-delog`. Here is the file: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3ZMv9hh4R9/

Comment: it should be your `username/repoName` in your GitHub

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Github OAuth Client ID**

-Goto Github Developer Settings

-New OAuth

-Enter Application name

-Homepage URL as Netlify URL

-And Authorization callback URL to https://api.netlify.com/auth/done)

Once Client ID and Secret token is generated configure same in Netlify Access Control as described:

**Accessing Netlify CMS Admin**

-Goto your Netlify site admin

-Goto Access Control > OAuth then Install Provider you need to select provider as Github as add Client ID and Secret

-Your Netlify CMS is ready. Goto you netlify site URL and append /admin/. for example example.netlify.com/admin/, You will see login with Github button.

=> If that doesn't work, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the site in Netlify App and then: Site settings -> Identity -> Services. Under Git Gateway click 'Edit Settings' and then 'Generate access token in GitHub'. A popup will appear where you grant permissions. Save it. Done.